# How to save and retrieve contentUrl in Kendo Tabstrip

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I use Telerik MVC HtmlHelper to create a Tabstrip in which I want to store url for each tab and retrive it in onTabSelect and get html content from the url. The code is,

```
<% Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
    .Name("TabStrip")
    .Items(tabstrip =>
    {
        tabstrip.Add()
            .Text("Tab1")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "tab", url = "/Maintenance/AthletesGeneralInfo/", tabNumber = "1" })
            .Content(() =>
                { ...
                });
    })
    .ClientEvents(e => e.OnSelect("onTabSelect"))
    .SelectedIndex(0)
    .Render();
%>

function onTabSelect(e)
{
    var resourceId = $('#resourceId').val();
    refreshTab($(e.item).attr("tabNumber"), $(e.item).attr("url"));
}
```

It works fine. Now I want to make it work in Kendo. But onTabSelect() is no longer working in $(e.item).attr("url"). I'd like to know how to store url in Kendo Tabstrip (perhaps as contentUrl and no longer in HtmlAttributes) and retrieve it in Jquery. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use tabstip.LoadContentFrom() method like in this example: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/tabstrip/ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use LoadContentFrom as follows,

```
tabstrip.Add()
.Text("Tab1")
.LoadContentFrom("AthletesResults", "Maintenance", new { id = ViewData["resourceId"]});
```